# How to include Apache Commons IO in Eclipse? (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I configure my Eclipse installation to use classes from Apache [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/)?

I want to use this code:

```
IOUtil.write(encoded, new FileOutputStream(new File("target-file.txt")))
```

But it gives the error:

> IOUtil cannot be resolved

Comment: Do you use any build tool, i. e. Ant or Maven or Ivy? They can help you with dependency management.

Comment: refer me to a link to know more about them and there usage

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/ http://maven.apache.org/ http://ant.apache.org/ivy/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770005/will-apache-ant-make-ioutil-class-usable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also can use build tools eclipse plugins like **[m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/)** or **[IAM](http://www.eclipse.org/iam/)** (formerly **[Q4e](http://code.google.com/p/q4e/)**).

IAM can  be be installed following [those instructions](http://code.google.com/p/q4e/wiki/Installation), and ha s a great [dependency viewer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/What%27s_in_IAM#Tooling)

[image]

Differences between m2eclipse and IAM are discussed [here](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-maven-you-should-be-using.html), [there](http://groups.google.com/group/q4e-users/browse_thread/thread/fdfc79a45f932e81) and [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.iam/msg00089.html).

> Q4E is event-oriented, I believe that m2e uses the console and stdin/out.
>
> A bigger one is that **m2eclipse forks and uses an external maven (for running maven goals) while `iam/q4e` only uses the embedder**.
> Our position here is that it is the way to go, allowing deep integration and better performance.
> It certainly has allowed us to quickly do things like the dependency analysis view and some other "magic" in the maven incremental builder.

Answer (score 8):

What you need to do is this:
[How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)
[image: add jar]

Answer (score 4):

Download Apache .jar files and add them to library through your IDE (Eclipse).

Comment: cant find it on the internet .. help me find it

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=apache+commons+io - somewhere among the first three hits, probably here: http://commons.apache.org/downloads/download_io.cgi