# Will Apache Ant make IOUtil class usable?

Tags: java, ant, apache-commons

Will Apache [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) classes be usable if I add [Apache Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) to the project build path?

I need to use IOUtil class. If no please provide the download link to the correct [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file.

Comment: What do you mean by useable? - the calsses are standard Java classes so will run as a normal class

Comment: i mean to say IOUtil is not getting resolved.. and i cant find any apache.jar on the internet to make use of  Apache commons IO classes help me out guys .. you can say take away my points if you want .. cause i'm new and have stupid questions to ask

Comment: Yes, agreed, but keep in mind, that at SO real persons try to solve your problems, and the community honors the personal effort spent on solving your own problem - and vice-versa. (see my answer for a solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest approach

1. Download [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) from the Apache foundations website
2. create a folder 'lib' in your eclipse project and copy the commons library (jar) in it
3. right-click the project and do a refresh (if the library is not yet displayed)
4. right-click the library and do "Build Path" - "Add to build path"

(I don't have the eclipse up and running, hope the menu and action names are correct)

Comment: and please - use google/bing/etc first, with 'apache commons io' you'd found it quite easy on the web

Answer (score 7):

Grumpy Old Mlk Time (bye bye rep points):
You have to actually learn Java and the tools not just string together odd snippets of code.

In this case I recommend you head back to your [original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769776/writing-a-byte-array-to-a-file-in-java/1769788#1769788) on this subject and read the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) I posted and ignore Commons IO for now. You are going to a lot of trouble to avoid a very small amount of boiler plate code.

One you have done that it might be worth reading a little about the [classpath](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html) and how one configures that (called the build path) in Eclipse.

Comment: +1 for patience and being honest :) (I bet, the next question is something like: 'please define use of classpath' or so)

Comment: +1 If only there was a "grumpy old fart" badge. I'd have 2 dozen of them by now.

Comment: +1 from me as well, I think you're right; @Andreas_D yup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769889/how-to-include-apache-commons-io-in-eclipse-java

Comment: @skaffman - should we ask for this on meta.stackoverlow ? Along with the "in my day..." badge...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they'll be just as useable as if you hadn't added Ant.

Comment: actually i forgot to add that they are not usable now.. i dont know how to add apache commons io to make it usable i though adding ants would make it usable .

Comment: Nope, Ant is a build tool, not a fix for an incomplete classpath.