# How to import a jar in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

How do I import a jar in Eclipse?

Answer (score 410, accepted):

You can add a jar in Eclipse by right-clicking on the Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar. A quick demo [here](http://tech.bragboy.com/2016/01/quick-way-to-import-jar-in-eclipse.html).

[image]

The above solution is obviously a "Quick" one. However, if you are working on a project where you need to commit files to the source control repository, I would recommend adding Jar files to a dedicated library folder within your source control repository and referencing few or all of them as mentioned above.

Comment: I think it should be : `Add External JARs"

Comment: For me it's 'Add External Archives'.

Comment: What about including jar doc?

Comment: The menu options are "Project > Properties > Java Build Path" in ADT v22.2.1 (October 2013).

Comment: should I insert them under modulepath or classpath ?

Answer (score 206):

Adding external Jar is not smart in case you want to change the project location in filesystem.

The best way is to add the jar to build path so your project will compile if exported:

1. Create a folder called lib in your project folder.
2. copy to this folder all the jar files you need.
3. Refresh your project in eclipse.
4. Select all the jar files, then right click on one of them and select Build Path -> Add to Build Path

Comment: You dont need to click each one, just select them all, then do step 4

Comment: @Hesham Do we have to create a folder with the name lib or can it be anything other than it?

Comment: @Rameshwar it can be anything

Comment: Best answer so you don't accidentally use a jar file that is not in your project directory

Comment: "4.Select all the jar files..."  This is imprecise.  Select from where?  This is the key point and I am still confused.

Comment: @BaruchAtta in your project tree structure, after steps 1–3, you should find *ProjectName* > src > *package_name* > *package_name*.lib and expand it. It should show the jar files in your lib folder. These are the ones you should select and add to your build path.

Comment: This is an opinion, not an answer. There are valid reasons why one may want a fixed or shared 3rd party library location, that just doesn't fit Eclipse's model.

Answer (score 101):

Two choices:

1/ From the project:

[image]

2/ If you have already other jar imported, from the directory "References Libraries":

[image]

Both will lead you to this screen where you can mange your libraries:

[image]

Comment: Add Jar vs Add External Jar what's the differnce?

Comment: @Pacerier "Add jars" is referring to jars directly accessible from within your workspace. Their path is relative to a project from your workspace, instead of an absolute path. "Add External Jars" is for jars stored anywhere else (on your hard drive or on the LAN/WAN), and uses an absolute path.

Comment: @VonC Just curious, what program did you use to take your screenshots? There's nothing built in to windows to get shots with right-click menus showing, and I like the drop-shadowed cutoff bits.

Comment: @localhost see the comments of this 4-years old question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2685618/6309. Or that one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612688/6309. Or the meta-post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775

Answer (score 11):

Here are the steps:

1. click File > Import. The Import window opens.
2. Under Select an import source, click J2EE > App Client JAR file.
3. Click Next.
4. In the Application Client file field, enter the location and name of the application client JAR file that you want to import. You can click the Browse button to select the JAR file from the file system.
5. In the Application Client project field, type a new project name or select an application client project from the drop-down list. If you type a new name in this field, the application client project will be created based on the version of the application client JAR file, and it will use the default location.
6. In the Target runtime drop-down list, select the application server that you want to target for your development. This selection affects the run time settings by modifying the class path entries for the project.
7. If you want to add the new module to an enterprise application project, select the Add project to an EAR check box and then select an existing enterprise application project from the list or create a new one by clicking New.

   **Note**: If you type a new enterprise application project name, the enterprise application project will be created in the default location with the lowest compatible J2EE version based on the version of the project being created. If you want to specify a different version or a different location for the enterprise application, you must use the New Enterprise Application Project wizard.
8. Click Finish to import the application client JAR file.

Answer (score 5):

Just a comment on importing jars into Eclipse (plug-in development) projects:

In case you are developing Eclipse plug-ins, it makes sense to use Eclipse's native bundling mechanism instead of just importing the jar into a plug-in project. Eclipse (or better its underlying OSGi runtime, Equinox) uses so-called bundles which contain some more information than plain jars (e.g., version infos, dependencies to other bundles, exported packages; see the MANIFEST.MF file). Because of this information, OSGi bundles can be dynamically loaded/unloaded and there is automatic dependency resolution available in an OSGi/Eclipse runtime. Hence, using OSGi bundles instead of plain jars (contained inside another OSGi bundle) has some advantages.

(BTW: Eclipse plug-ins are the same thing as OSGi bundles.)

There is a good chance that somebody already bundled a certain (3rd party) library as an OSGi bundle. You might want to take a look at the following bundle repositories:

- http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/
- http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/
- http://www.osgi.org/Repository/HomePage

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries -> New(Name it) -> Add external Jars

(I recommend dragging your new libraries into the eclipse  folder before any of these steps to keep everything together, that way if you reinstall Eclipse or your OS you won't have to rwlink anything except the JDK) Now select the jar files you want. Click OK.

Right click on your project and choose Build Path -> Add Library

FYI just code and then right click and Source->Organize Imports

Answer (score 2):

### Jar File in the system path is:

> C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar

ojdbc14.jar(it's jar file)

### To import jar file in your Eclipse IDE, follow the steps given below.

1. Right-click on your project
2. Select Build Path
3. Click on Configure Build Path
4. Click on Libraries, select Modulepath and select Add External JARs
5. Select the jar file from the required folder
6. Click and Apply and Ok

Answer (score 0):

first of all you will go to your project what you are created
and next right click in your mouse and select properties in the bottom 
and select build in path in the left corner and add external jar file add click apply .that's it

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse I included a compressed jar file i.e. zip file. Eclipse allowed me to add this zip file as an external jar but when I tried to access the classes in the jar they weren't showing up.

After a lot of trial and error I found that using a zip format doesn't work. When I added a jar file then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click on the Project.
2. Click on Build Path.
3. Click On Configure Build Path.
4. Under Libraries, Click on Add Jar or Add External Jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a trouble on udemy course of chad on springboot for the importing the jar. Then follow these steps.

1. Right click on the project.
2. You will see a option of Build Path, click on it.
3. You will have a option of Configure Build path, click on it.
4. Go to libraries.
5. Then go to the place where you have a jar files make them into a new folder and upload on a new place.
6. Then click on Add External Jars, you will surely be able to upload it which will help on classpathxmlapplicationcontext as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: don't delete Registry keys directly.. because this make errors of install IDEs! Zum Beispiel: Netbeans 20 in C:/Programm Files/Netbeans .. /ide/modules/org.eclipse [..] core.jar's files etc. etc. Auf wiedersehen!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).