# How can I add JAR files to the web-inf/lib folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse and I need to be able to add Java libraries (JAR files) into my web application's `WEB-INF/lib` folder. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Just copy the jar file into `WEB-INF/lib`. BTW: `WEB-INF` must be all uppercase.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

- Add the jar file to your WEB-INF/lib folder.
- Right-click your project in Eclipse, and go to "Build Path > Configure Build Path"
- Add the "Web App Libraries" library

This will ensure all WEB-INF/lib jars are included on the classpath.

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution.
This problem happens, when you import a project.

The solution is simple

1. Right click -> Properties
2. Project Facets -> Check Dyanmic Web Module and Java Version
3. Apply Setting.

Now you should see the web app libraries showing your jars added.

Comment: omg this finally owkred for me, facet was 1.6 but build 1.7 :)

Comment: I tried this and it most definitely caused an issue. My META-INF > jdoconfig.xml file became full of "errors' which I am convinced are not real errors because the file is a complete replicate of it's head revision. Also, when I then unchecked Dynamic Web Module the problems did not go away.

Answer (score 3):

Pasting the jar files in WebContent\WEB-INF\lib via the file system was the only way it worked for me.

They then appeared under the Deployed Resources and WebContent lib sub-folders.

When I looked, the build path had the jars in the Web App Libraries and everything built and ran fine.

Answer (score 3):

1. add the jar to WEB-INF/lib from file structure
2. refresh the project, you should see the jar now visible under the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 2):

They are automatically added to the project classpath if its a web project. Sometimes it does not work properly, a refresh or close/open of the project helps.

if its not a web project you can right click on the library and go to "Build Path" -> "Add to Build Path"

Comment: Yes, a requirement to this is that the "Web App Libraries" are added to the Build Path as MikeG wrote.

Answer (score 2):

add the jar to WEB-INF/lib from file structure
refresh the project, you should see the jar now visible under the WEB-INF/lib folder.

this is the best solution that worked for me

Comment: If all you wan is to put a jar in the classpath, Eclipse offers standard support as described in this rather old  [stackoverflow question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Check under project properties -> deployment assembly
if jar file are under deployed path- WEB-INF/lib
if not use add button and add jar under WEB-INF/lib

sometime eclipse (in my case Juno Service Release 2 ) was not doing it for me so i did manually. this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the ToolBar to go
`Project> Properties>Java Build Path > Add External Jars`.
Locate the File on the local disk or web Directory and Click Open.

This will automatically add the required Jar files to the Library.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone,  if you are using a Git repo, make sure the jars make it into the WEB-INF/lib INSIDE the git repo and not just in the project WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar file to your WEB-INF/lib folder.
Right-click your project in Eclipse, and go to "Build Path > Configure Build Path"
Add the "Web App Libraries" library
This will ensure all WEB-INF/lib jars are included on the classpath. 
helped me..

Drag and drop in WEB-INF/lib folder and restart eclipse ans start webservice then create client