# Add external jar files into a particular library in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, gradle, dependency-management

I was looking for a way to add the downloaded jar files under a particular library (In this case, I would like to add jars under "Gradle Dependencies" which already contains some jars inside).

I was attempting to use [" Build Path > Configure Build Path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440479/how-can-i-add-jar-files-to-the-web-inf-lib-folder-in-eclipse) but the jar files I added are under the "root" directory above "Gradle Dependencies"
Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Gradle Dependencies** "library" (it's proper name in Eclipse vernacular is Classpath Container) is managed by the Gradle plugin and is not directly editable by the user. To add something to that library, you'd have to include it in your Gradle build file (`build.gradle`).

Normally you don't specify local JARs as Gradle dependencies (like Maven, Gradle wants all dependencies to be located in a repository). But if you *really* want that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700183/639520