# Error while performing servlet and hibernate connectivity with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, servlets

this is my ecxeption plz tel me what to do?

i have set all the property of hibernate and also did mapping with pojo class also but after index page it shows error

```
>  exception


         javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
         org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



>  root cause

          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session

            com.controller.insert.doPost(insert.java:27)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)




      root cause
      java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
        com.controller.insert.doPost(insert.java:27)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

this is servlet code here blmanager is a class which contains sessionfactory and emp1 is pojo class

```
     package com.controller;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.blmanager.blmanager;
    import com.pojo.emp1;


    public class insert extends HttpServlet {




        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            String name=request.getParameter("name");

            blmanager bl=new blmanager();
            emp1 em=new emp1();
            em.setName(name);
            bl.insert(em);
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include specify the jar containing org.hibernate.Session class either in your WEB-INF/lib folder of your war, or in the library folder of your web container.

Comment: i have added jar but shows same error.

Comment: here com.controller is my package and insert in servlet file

Comment: where have you added the jar? if you are using maven and added hibernate-3.0.1.jar in your own jar, you need to indicate that the jar is "provided" in your pom.xml. if you put the jar in the lib of your container, you need to remove that "provided" indication.

Comment: no i am not using maven.i have added external jar in Liberaries

Comment: just try including the jar in your WEB-INF/lib as well, just to make sure.

Comment: how do i add jar in lib folder of web-inf

Comment: if you are using Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440479/how-can-i-add-jar-files-to-the-web-inf-lib-folder-in-eclipse

Comment: did every thing u said but still not working

Comment: have you created hibernate datasource configuration file?

Comment: yes hbm file i have created

Answer (score 0):

Looks like hibernate.jar is missing. Kindly provide list of jars you are using also your project structure. If you are using maven as a build tool you can use below set of dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If you are not using maven, make sure all the dependencies listed above are added to WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: hibernate3.jar is nam of jar file link:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhibernate3jar.htm