# Correct way to add a .jar file into /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder of a Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse, import, jar

I need to add *jstl-1.2.jar* to my *Dynamic Web Project* in Eclipse (Eclipse for Java EE, 4.9.0 version) to enable JSTL support for Tomcat.

I need to add this file into `/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder of my project:

[image]

But when I right-click that "lib" folder and choose `import` from context menu, importing does not work. `Import->General->File System` does not see jar files (they are inaccessible for import), `Import->General->Archive File` sees jar files, but imports a jar file as a lot of .class files which is not what needed. All other import options are inappropriate.

I found a workaround - I can successfully do it bypassing Eclipse: add my jar file into `/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` simply using Windows Explorer outside of Eclispe and then refresh project from Eclipse. The jar turns out to be on the build path.

But normally when **working with any IDE doing stuff not with IDE built-in tools is conceptually wrong.
What is the correct way to achieve what I am doing with my workaround?**

P.S. I realize that [this is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440479/how-can-i-add-jar-files-to-the-web-inf-lib-folder-in-eclipse) the added jar file turns on to be on the build-path: `Web App Libraries` was added to the Libraries tab by default (I didn't even have to press "Add Library" button)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you add your libraries to the Java Build Path check also the `Deployment Assembly` tab and verify that your deployment setup is correct, that all needed application libraries are added to /WEB-INF/lib (you dont need to go to explorer and add them manually!)

for example:

[image: Deployment Assembly tab]
This means, all under src (source) will end up in the web-inf/classes (compiled!), and all under WebContent will be in your root (html,jsp, images, etc as the path layout you have organized!). And finally that your libraries will be in web-inf/lib. This way you can also do an export of the WAR / EAR and verify the bundle setup!