# How can I add some.jar file into libs and WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folders with Eclipse IDE means?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

How can I add some.jar file into `libs` and `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folders through Eclipse IDE means? I have a Dynamic Web Project and Eclipse Photon (EE version).

Yes, I can use Windows File Explorer *outside* of Eclipse to copy-paste jar files into those folders.

[image]

But it seems I cannot do it with Eclipse: when I try to right-click on those folders and then do `Import->General->Archive File` (unpacked jar is imported as a buch of files/folders) or `Import->General->File System` (jar file is not even visible in respective wizard window) - nothing works.

[image]

P.S. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440479/how-can-i-add-jar-files-to-the-web-inf-lib-folder-in-eclipse) also indicates there is no way to do it inside Eclipse (this answer addresses another issue of being able to use the lib you already have in WEB-INF/lib folder so that the project compiles and gets deployed OK).

Comment: We're not seeing it not being shown, but can you copy from Windows Explorer and paste into WEB-INF/lib inside Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I can! And that is a solution for me. Thank you! But strange I cannot do it with some context menu or something. But just copy-paste (ctrl+V) does put a jar into WEB-INF/lib folder