# I want to get library for com.google.android.maps to add my project

Tags: android

I want com.google.android.maps library.

I am just creating a demo for Map on android mobile but at the `extends MapActivity` it give error to create the class.

any downloadable link.

thanks in advance.

Comment: which api are using right now ? Means SDK Platform .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to download Google Api,and set build target as that Google Api.So that you can extend map activity.

**OR**

you can find maps library from android-sdk-tools -> add-ons -> your api version.

Comment: That is only method? i want downlaod Maps.jar or lib and put into may project and then i want to extends MapActivity? is this phisible?

Comment: what it mean android-sdk-tools -> add-ons -> your api version? i didn;t found it.

Answer (score 8):

You can find the maps.jar in the android-sdk folder on you file system

`{ANDROID-SDK_HOME}\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\libs`

[image]

Comment: but still MapActivity if not found.

Comment: I added a screen shot The MapActivity is present in my setup did you add it to the classpath?

Comment: no i didn't do that. is this necessary to add into class path? only add library is not sufficient? and i just get Maps.rar what should i do now.

Comment: see for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Download jar file from following link:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidgooglemapsapi11jar.htm

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit old thread but someone might find it useful.

I had issues with Google Maps V1 and a dependency on it as suddenly `dependencies` in Gradle were not loading `compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'` [which includes Maps V1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040377/what-is-difference-between-compilesdkversion-google-inc-google-apis23-and-co/36040409), I switched to `compileSdkVersion 23` and got bunch of compile errors similar to OPs problem with `extends MapActivity`. I went on to look for Jars for Maps V1 and found them hiding in:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml

List includes bunch of pointers to various `zip` files eg:

```
...
<archives>
  <archive>
    <!-- Built on: Mon Aug 15 05:06:51 2016. -->
    <complete>
      <size>86099835</size>
      <checksum>e9999f4fa978812174dfeceec0721c793a636e5d</checksum>
      <url>google_apis-12_r01.zip</url>
    </complete>
  </archive>
</archives>
...
```

In order to download that zip file you need to take `<url>` value and add it to `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/` which would end up looking like:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-12_r01.zip

And after you download and unzip, you will get the sources:

```
google_apis-12_r01
  |
  |-docs
  |-images
  |-libs
  |  |
  |  |- maps.jar
  |  \- usb.jar
  |
  |-samples
  \-manifest.ini
```

Afterwards just drop `maps.jar` to `libs` directory, make sure it is loaded in dependencies `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` and your project should compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the downloadable maps.jar http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidgooglemapsapi8jar.htm