# what is difference between compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' and compileSdkVersion 23

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Inside the Gradle.build file I see some projects using

```
compileSdkVersion="'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23"
```

and some are just using the number

```
compileSdkVersion="23"
```

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The latter one is correct for the vast majority of projects.

The former one would only be needed for apps using the long-since-deprecated Maps V1 API.