# The type org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Using this code :

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

I receive this Eclipse error:

```
The type org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
```

at line `String str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);`

There are three 'JsonGenerationException' class types on my class path (you may have to save the image and open it separately to read the text in the image):

[image]

Is the reason I'm receiving this error message because JsonGenerationException is in two different jar files and Eclipse is unsure which on to use ? If so how can I fix it ?

I required this jar file : http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.4

Comment: Make sure that the JAR containing `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException` is on your classpath.

Comment: @reprogrammer your comment pointed me in right direction. Please see edit

Comment: Did requiring that JAR fix the issue?

Comment: @reprogrammer yep, add your answer into a comment ill accept.

Comment: OK. Turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that the JAR containing `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException` is on your classpath, e.g., by using [jackson-core-asl POM](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.4/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.pom).

Comment: Hi, I am new to Java. Having the same problem. When I tried to import org.codehaus.jackson.map, it shows the error message "cannot be resolved". I read your reply but don't know how to use this xml file and where to put it. I assume it's under Configure build path, right? Could you please walk me through the process? Thanks.

Comment: I downloaded GOOGLE-API-CLIENT, but there is no org.codehauls.jackson.JsonGenerationException folder.

Comment: Worked for me, if anyone is wondering how to add jar to classpath check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

and also,you have to add `jackson-core-asl-XXX.jar` to build path.