# ServletException, HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee, compiler-errors

I got an error while creating a servlet in eclipse like

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - ServletException cannot be resolved to a 
>      type
> - HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved 
>      to a type
> - HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to 
>      a type

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Two possible issues could be

- you either forgot to include Servlet jar in your classpath
- you forgot to import it in your Servlet class

To include Servlet jar in your class path in eclipse, Download the latest [Servlet Jar](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) and configure using buildpath option. look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse) for more info.

If you have included the jar make sure that your import is declared.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
```

Comment: it may be best to point to the application servers runtime instead of pulling in servlet.jar

Answer (score 37):

You can do the following:

1. import the jar file inside your class:

   Old Way: `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`

   New Way: `import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet`
2. Add the Apache Tomcat library:

   Follow these steps:

> 1. Right-click on your Project from Side Menu
> 2. click `Properties` (alt + enter)
> 3. Search for `java Build Path`
> 4. Click on `Libraries`
> 5. Click on `Add library` from the right side menu
> 6. Choose `server runtime` and click `next`
> 7. Choose Apache Tomcat v10 (any version which is available to you)
> 8. Click `Finish` then `Apply Changes`

Also, First of all, make sure that the Servlet jar is included in your class path in eclipse as PermGenError said.

This will solve your error.

Answer (score 22):

Select Tomcat server in Targeted Runtime

Project->Properties->Targeted Runtimes (Select your Tomcat Server)

Comment: Thank you! It works! Choose e.g. for javax.servlet-api-3.1.0 the TomCat 8.0

Answer (score 8):

Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add library from library tab > Choose server runtime > Next > choose Apache Tomcat v 7.0> Finish > Ok

Answer (score 4):

if you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Are the classes imported?  Try pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `O` to resolve the imports.  If this does not work you need to include the application servers runtime libraries.

1. Windows > Preferences
2. Server > Runtime Environment
3. Add
4. Select your appropriate environment, click Next
5. Point to the install directory and click Finish.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a reason of this problem, some code is broken or undefined.You may see an error in a java class such as "The type javax.servlet.http.HttpSession cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files". you shuold download " [javax.servlet.jar"](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) as mentioned before. Then configure your project build path, add the javax.servlet.jar as an external jar.I hope it fixes the problem.At least it worked for me.