# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rexsl/test/AssertionPolicy

Tags: java

I'm trying to validate simple HTML file with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   String xhtml = "<html><body><p>Hello, world!</p></body></html>";
   ValidationResponse response = new ValidatorBuilder().html().validate(xhtml);
   System.out.println(response.valid());
}
```

And result:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/rexsl/test/AssertionPolicy    at
>   com.rexsl.w3c.ValidatorBuilder.(ValidatorBuilder.java:64)     at
>   HTMLValidator.main(HTMLValidator.java:10)

How to fix this?

Comment: This simply means that you have not included all the required Jar files in your class path. What external libraries are you using? Also mention the link to library which you are using, so that we can look that API's documentation.

Comment: Add jar to Build path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception appears when *JVM* can't find a specific *Class* at *runtime*.

Make sure that:

- *Class* is available in *Java Classpath*.
- If you are running your program using *JAR* command, make sure *Class* is defined in *Class-Path attribute*.