# Use Sphinx4-1.0beta6 in a Project

Tags: java, voice, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

**How do you setup Sphinx 4 to be able to use it in applications?**
I know there is documentation [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/),but I can't seem to get it to work. If anyone could provide a step by step list it would be great.

This what I've tried:

1. Download sphinx and Apache ANT
2. Install ANT (It works fine)
3. Run the JSAPI.exe File to unpack JSAPI.jar
4. Build the whole directory using "ant" in the command line

I can run demo builds but have no clue as to how to add Sphinx to my own program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sphinx4 API is provided by a single jar - sphinx4/lib/sphinx4.jar. You only need to include this jar into classpath or into the project in IDE and use the API. Sometimes you need to include other jars from sphinx4/lib folder.

For tutorial on using sphinx4 see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial

it has sphinx4 section which will help you to start with the API. Also see the code of sphinx4 demos.

To get idea how to include jar into the IDE project, study IDE documentation. Here is the howto for Eclipse:

[How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)