# Xuggler installation

Tags: java, eclipse, screenshot, xuggler, xuggle

I know this has been hashed over a bit on here, but I have an issue that hasn't been answered.  I am attempting to install Xuggler plug it into Eclipse.  I have no issues with the idea of adding it to my classpath, my issue is with getting my hands on the actual xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar file.  I've installed the one from the website, but there is only a zip folder, and not a jar file.  I even tried to pack the file into a jar myself, but Eclipse wouldn't take it.  I've looked everywhere in that zip folder and I haven't seen a jar file anywhere.  Should just use the zip folder, or did I mess something up?  I saw something where a guy had a xuggler file in his Program Files, but I don't have that.

EDIT:

I've been to the googleCode site given on the Xuggler website, and I've clicked on the one that says xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar.  For some reason, though, when I do this, it tries to install as a zip folder, not as a jar.  Then it doesn't work in my classpath.  When it installs as a zip, like it does in my case, there *is no* xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar file on my computer.  Instead, the file that was installed is now xuggle-xuggler-5.4.zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Eclipse myself, so I'm not familiar with your particular problem. I do use Xuggler however, and have successfully used the JAR found on their website. So here's just a couple of quick hints. I apologize if I am telling you things you already know.

- You can find jar-builds for Xuggler [here](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/). Somehow they chose to hide the link on their website somewhat.
- There have been previous questions on StackOverflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse), regarding instructions to add a JAR to an Eclipse project, which will automatically update the classpath and include the JAR during build.
- JAR's are in a format that was extended from ZIP, as can be read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29). It is unfair to say that JAR files and ZIP files are the same, but you could open a JAR file like you would a ZIP file and read (some) of its content.
- Xuggler clearly states this on their website, but I missed it myself, so I thought I'd mention this. The `xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar` can be used on any platform. Depending on the codecs you will be using, you might need some additional libraries. To save some disk space you could use `xuggle-xuggler-noarch-5.4.jar` and an appropriate `xuggle-xuggler-arch-xxx.jar` as a replacement for `xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar`.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thanks for your answer!  I actually have no idea what caused the error but I ended up renaming the zip file to a jar file and it worked just fine.  I think it might have been some wacko setting for 7zip or something.  Any chance you explain to me what it means by "ERROR: Could not write header for container."?  All of these errors and methods are alien to me and I'm having trouble figuring them out.

Comment: Weirdest thing is I have been getting those errors as well, and my files have been playing fine by only writing a trailer. That gets rid of the errors for me, though it seems to throw "Cannot write trailer without header" errors for some others. If you need anymore help you should probably post a new question with some code attached. Could you mark this one as answered? :)

Comment: Okay.  Next time I get around to working on it I'll post another question.  Thanks for your help!