# mule-Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.5.9:wsdl2java (default) on project : javax/xml/ws/Action

Tags: web-services, maven, mule, mule-studio

I'm following http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation... to create a connector to a SOAP Service via CXF Client Example. When I add the required maven dependency code in ,pom file and clean and run it(on mule studio)...I'm getting the following error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.5.9:wsdl2java (default) on project sunsetriseconnector: javax/xml/ws/Action
```

The full stack trace looks like this :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sunset Sunrise Service 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> studio-maven-plugin:3.4.2:studio (default-cli) @ sunsetriseconnector >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mule-devkit-maven-plugin:3.4.0:attach-test-resources (default-attach-test-resources) @      sunsetriseconnector ---
[INFO] Attaching test resource D:\MuleExamples\sunsetrise\src\main\app
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0-alpha-4:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @   sunsetriseconnector ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mule-devkit-maven-plugin:3.4.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ sunsetriseconnector ---
[INFO] Source directory: D:\MuleExamples\sunsetrise\target\generated-sources\mule added
[INFO] Resource directory: D:\MuleExamples\sunsetrise\target\generated-sources\mule added
[INFO] Sorting generator executing based on their dependencies...
[INFO] Searching for classes annotated with @Connector
[INFO] Validating sunsetriseConnector class
[INFO] Validating Multi-module consistency
[INFO] Adding registry bootstrap entry for   org.tutorial.sunsetrise.agents.DefaultSplashScreenAgent as DefaultSplashScreenAgent
[INFO] Generating message processor as org.tutorial.sunsetrise.processors.MyProcessorMessageProcessor for method myProcessor in sunsetriseConnector
[INFO] Generating config element definition parser as   org.tutorial.sunsetrise.config.sunsetriseConnectorConfigDefinitionParser for class sunsetriseConnector
[INFO] Generating bean definition parser as org.tutorial.sunsetrise.config.MyProcessorDefinitionParser for message processor org.tutorial.sunsetrise.processors.MyProcessorMessageProcessor
[INFO] Validating example for method: myProcessor
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger    (org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:2.5.9:wsdl2java (default) @ sunsetriseconnector ---
 May 2, 2014 12:18:13 PM org.apache.cxf.xjc.bg.BooleanGetterPlugin run
INFO: Running boolean getter plugin.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.464s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 02 12:18:13 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/62M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.5.9:wsdl2java (default) on   project sunsetriseconnector: javax/xml/ws/Action -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I'm pretty new in mule and also in Apache cxf. Please help me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix by adding **jaxws-api-2.2.1.jar** inside *C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\jre\lib\endorsed* folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MuleStudio, which is built on Eclipse, you should import the JAR into your build path. See [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

If you're using Mule ESB Standalone, you should drop the JAR into the MULE_HOME/apps/yourapp/lib directory if you need it on a per-app basis, or in the /MULE_HOME/lib/user

See [the class loader documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Classloader+Control+in+Mule)