# NanoHTTPD: How do I add it to a current Java eclipse project and use it?

Tags: java, eclipse, package, nanohttpd

This is my first time with Java and Eclipse. I started a brand new Java project and I want to import/add NanoHTTPD into it. How do you this?

This is NanoHTTPD's site: http://nanohttpd.com

Thanks!

**Edit**

Lesson learned, be specific or you get backslashed for asking. I edited the question and here's some background and the problem I'm running into.

I'm developing a Nodejs backend that needs to query a JAVA project I was given. Pipes are a no go because the services will run on different machines. Tomcat seems like an overkill so I decided to use NanoHTTPD to develop the web service. I come from Ruby & Nodejs so compilation and Eclipse are very new to me. First off, I have no JAR file just TAR and ZIP and from what I read they are fundamentally different. However, I tried importing the TAR and ZIP files as recommended but the structure I get in Eclipse does not seem right compared to the JRE System Library or others I've seen. Notwithstanding, I went ahead and tried to import the package from my Main.java file

```
package fi.iki.elonen;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Main");
    }
}
```

When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
at Main.main(Main.java:4)
```

I found a great article from IBM ["Managing the Java classpath (UNIX and Mac OS X)"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-classpath-unix/) where it mentions that an IDE such as Eclipse can alleviate the pain of dealing with the source path, classpath and compilation. Unfortunately, I'm afraid this is where I might be getting stuck.

I tried uploading images of what I have but apparently I'm not popular enough yet to do it.

Could someone help me figuring out how to not only import libraries but using them on projects? Even just a URL to a clear Linux/Mac OS X post that explains import with multiple packages would be great.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse/3280384#3280384 or https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F or http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Answer (score 2):

NanoHTTPD is designed to be very lightweight.

I just cut and pasted the 'NanoHTTPD' class from the source on github, its all in there - and pasted it as a class into my own project.

Then I created a subclass of nanoHTTPD, overrode the 'serve' method to send my own stuff and it was job done.

Answer (score 0):

Download the jar, drag it into the project, and right-click it to add it to the build path.

Comment: sir, from where can I get the nano httpd jar?