# How to use jscience constants in java?

Tags: java, jscience

I need some of the scientific constants for my project and i found jscience lib. but i can't find a way to use jscience constants. 
I see the [TUTORIAL](http://jscience.org/api/overview-summary.html#TUTORIAL) but there was nothing to explain how to use constants.

So how can i use constants in jscience?
And is any more tutorial or samples of use this lib?

Answer (score 1):

You import them :

```
 import static org.jscience.physics.units.SI.*; // Static import.
 ...
 Unit<Pressure> HECTO_PASCAL = HECTO(PASCAL);
 Unit<Length> KILO_METER = KILO(METER);
```

Look at the javadoc at http://jscience.org/api/ , you will find many examples.

EDIT:

Actually it's

```
 import static javax.measure.unit.SI.*; // Static import.
```

The example in the javadoc is wrong about the package name.

Comment: thanks for your attention but when i import  "import static org.jscience.physics.units.SI.*; // Static import." eclipse say "The import org.jscience.physics.units cannot be resolved" (i add jscience to my lib folder)

Comment: You need to add the jscience jar to the build path of your Eclipse project. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: In your project, do you see Referenced Libraries ? Do you see jscience.jar ? Can you see the packages in the referenced jar ?

Comment: Well, it should work :-)  I see that's an Android project maybe it's  related. What happens if you do a plain Java project with a regular JDK ?

Comment: Change my example to  `javax.measure.unit.SI.*`  , the provided example in the javadoc is wrong...