# How to add (import) java websocket library to my project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, websocket

First, sorry if question is trivial - I'm new to java world.

So, I've created new project. Then I downloaded websocket jar file here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavawebsocket130jar.htm

After that I've created 'lib' dir, copyed jar file there, selected it, added to build path.

Basically, I was following instructions from here:

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Then I copied source code into my class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl;
import org.java_websocket.framing.Framedata;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;
```

So, first part of imports is ok...standard Java imports. But problem is second group. For every import, starting from:

```
import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
```

I'm getting error "Import.... can not be resolved." And rest of the code that's using those classes is shooting errors because of that of course.

So, I added jar file to build path, but I still can't import classes from that library. What's missing here?

Comment: The problem is the jar you provided doesn't have those classes inside of it (WebSocket, WebSocketImpl etc).

Comment: What I have to do then? How can I add websocket library to my project?

Comment: It depends, there's many libraries. I use Tyrus; http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.tyrus

Comment: But what's the workflow? If I want to add that websocked, I mentioned above is it enough to add jar file and add it to a build path? And what's the purpose of build file if it doesn't contain those classes? Am I using wrong jar file or what?

Comment: When I change extension of jar file to zip I see structure there: org/java_websocket/WebSocket.java and iside that file there is WebSocket interface.

Comment: Yeah my bad I accidentally downloaded the file from the other download link which had no classes in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, extract the jar from the zip file, then right click the folder you're working on in your Eclipse. Click "Build path", then click "Configure Build Path", then click on "Libraries" and on the right hand side click on "Add external Jars", and then find your extracted jar.

Comment: By following that tutorial I already added it. So I had path to jar file under Build Path/Libraries as "local path" (don't know right expression). It was added as "chat/lib" ("chat" is name of my project). But I tried what  you suggested and now I have the same jar file listed twice. Only after adding it your way path is "windows path": "D:\eclipse\workspace\chat\lib". And that didn't help.

Comment: Is this the only way for adding library to eclipse? Maybe there is some other way? Inside jar file there is META-INF dir and inside it there is MANIFEST.MF file:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: david
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_15
Created-By: Apache Maven
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, try this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: I'm marking this as correct answer, because it is, but in my specific case it didn't helped me. However, I switched to NetBeans, found an example made specially for net beans and it worked like a charm. To bad there are no good websocket totorials for Eclipse. Thanks any way.

Answer (score -1):

Download the bundle from the below repository.

[MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.websocket/javax.websocket-api)

This should resolve your issues.