# how to include roboguice library in eclipse

Tags: android, roboguice

I have no idea about  how to install roboguice 3.0 in my eclipse,I searched a lot but none of the links didn't give me a clear desc about this..any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a dependency manager like Maven then I think these instructions are what you can use with eclipse https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/InstallationNonMaven Once you have the jars downloaded just follow these instructions for Eclipse [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

But I would highly suggest configuring something like Maven to manage your dependencies for you. Eclipse has good integration with them so you'll never have to worry about dependencies again.