# Shortcut for importing multiple jars in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, google-api, google-api-java-client

I am working on a [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java) for using Java to communicate with the Google Drive API.

I am currently on step 2, installing the Google Client Library. I installed the library, unzipped its contents and am ready to import the jar files into my project.

I am using [Import Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse) as a reference for importing jar files into my Eclipse project.

Here is a snapshot of all the jar files
[image]

Is there a  shortcut in the Java Build Path menu for importing all of these jar files at the same time, rather than individually adding each external jar? I tried add class folder(libs folder) but that didn't add all the JAR files.

Is it possible to write a program to do this?

Comment: Why you need to import the jars 40 times? While importing jars you can select all jars to add your class path?

Comment: Sorry I meant individually import all the jars. There's at least 40 different jars. When you add external jars, you only have the option of selecting one at at time. I was just wondering if there was a quick way to get all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the shift key down while clicking on additional jars to add within the folder. This will allow you to select and add more than one at a time.