# External jar not importing in Eclipse Project

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jar, import

I wish to parse JSON and for that I have downloaded java-json.jar file from [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip) URL.
I have added this in Build Path by

1. Right click on the Project
2. Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add External jars.
3. Selected the jar and it shows in the "Referenced Libraries"

But
    import org.json.JSONArray
gives me a error. Also when I stop at org. it gives me a few suggestions which does not include json.

What should I do to successfully import the json package?

Comment: Please follow this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse).

Comment: Check the .jar file's version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your project after including the jar.If it doesn't work, check whether the particular class you are looking for is present in the jar file or not.

Comment: The class is present. And I had rebuild it immediately after adding the jar. The error still persisted.

Comment: In that case just copy the jar into your project and then add it in your build path from "Add jars" and then again compile your project

Comment: It seems eclipse takes time to accept changes. I cleaned, rebuilt and restarted after adding the jars to build path but still it had errors. But I left the eclipse as is for a while and the error went away. Though I am curious as to what happened exactly.