# NoClassDefFound error in web application deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, web-applications, noclassdeffounderror

I am new to Java and trying to develop a Java web application with a feature to browse the server's file system. The functionality works fine when I run the application in Eclipse but if I generate a WAR file (via "Export as WAR" in Eclipse) and deploy on Tomcat 7, it throws a `NoClassDefFound` error.

I have placed the required jar in the `WEB-INB/lib` folder and also noticed the jar is available after deployment.

Comment: WEB-INB/ or WEB-INF ?

Comment: Hi, please post your full WAR layout first. Your application classes should reside in WEB-INF/classes. WEB-INF/lib is intended for libraries that are used by your classes.

Comment: I've had similar problems in past when packaging my app with war export on eclipse. I recommend you use for example Maven for this. Can you post the full stacktrace of your error?

Comment: @shi There's no reason you have to use `WEB-INF/classes` for anything.  You are free to put all your classes into a jar file that you include in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

first check your BuildPath. Your jars are added to build path are not.[check with this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Without the Exception trace can't provide more details, but try the following:

- Review the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error and identify the missing Java class.
- Verify and locate the missing Java class from your compile / build environment. 
  -Determine if the missing Java class is from your application code or third part API.
- Go to `Properties` on your Project (right click) > `Java Build Path` > `Order and Export`. Check all needed librarys are included.

Hope this helps.