# Problems with launching opencsv

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse as my Java Editor (I am a beginner with eclipse) and I want to use this CSV parsing library Open csv: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

So I downloaded the files and made a new Java-Project in eclipse. There is an example in those downloaded files and when I wanted to start it I got an error message: "Launch error: Selection does not contain a main type"

The code has a main method so I did not know what to do. Then I googled    my problem and read the advice to move the example-file into the src folder which I did. Now I get another error message when I run this code in the console: "CSVReader cannot be resolved to a type"

Here is the code that I want to run

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Copyright 2005 Bytecode Pty Ltd.
 * <p/>
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * <p/>
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * <p/>
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
    implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
public class AddressExample {

private static final String ADDRESS_FILE = "examples/addresses.csv";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(ADDRESS_FILE));
    String[] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Name: [" + nextLine[0] + "]\nAddress: [" + nextLine[1] + "]\nEmail: [" + nextLine[2] + "]");
    }

    // Try writing it back out as CSV to the console
    CSVReader reader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(ADDRESS_FILE));
    List<String[]> allElements = reader2.readAll();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(sw);
    writer.writeAll(allElements);

    System.out.println("\n\nGenerated CSV File:\n\n");
    System.out.println(sw.toString());


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the library from here [opencsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/)

And import them in your java project.
You can find the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Comment: Hi, I am not quite sure if I have done the right thing. I downloaded the jar and then I just imported it in my project as you mentioned and now I get a new error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at examples.AddressExample.main(AddressExample.java:28)

My project in the package explorer is still the same (which is the snapshot of the downloaded files and not the jar file itself)

Comment: Paste your exception in the question.. I think you haven't declared the package name correctly.

Comment: I have already pasted my exception in my previous post. But here is it again:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at examples.AddressExample.main(AddressExample.java:28)

Comment: Does anybody have a suggestion? 
kingAm wrote:"I think you haven't declared the package name correctly."
How can I declrade the package name correctly?