# How to create a servlet in an existing package of a project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have a Client-Server (Client and server are seperate projects in eclipse) system setup in Eclipse(Mars) I now need to create a servlet in a new package on the client project.

when I am creating a class and trying to extend HttpServlet to it I am getting an error saying javax.servlet cannot be resolved.

When I am trying File->New->Servlet I am being able to create a new Project altogether but unable to create a servlet in the existing project.

How should I resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried adding javax jar in your project?

Comment: No, how should i go about it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: It should be a separate project....its a web project

Answer (score 1):

You need do set up the "Java Build Path" of your project.
In eclipse, right-click on you project, "Build Path / Configure Build Path"

and there, in "Libraries" tab, you need to add a server runtime, that should contain servlet-api.jar

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are the Java platform technology of choice for extending and enhancing Web servers. Servlets provide a component-based, platform-independent method for building Web-based applications

See :

- [Java Servlet Technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html)
- [Java Servlets Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/index.html)

So when you try to create a servlet, it should be a separate project....its a web project.