# Exception with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql

i'm trying run code

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [root on Default schema]");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
        }
        return cn;
    }
```

but i get the exception:
[image]

with the dialog:

[image]

I have added the divier :mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar in this project.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You run it from eclipse? Have you add it as library? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: The JAR isn't in the CLASSPATH.  Put it there and find your next problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add [mysql connector](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6) jar to your project  classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```