# Using import acm.program for java?

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

Is there any standard coding syntax in java?

I was using `System.acm.println` while one of the stanford videos imports acm.program and use println for the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Java is a statically typed language and has a very specific syntax. Importing a package allows you to reference methods and classes within it without having to call it by it's full path. For example, if you write `import java.lang.Math;` then when you want to call the method `pow` you can write `Math.pow(param1, param2);` instead of `java.lang.Math.pow(param1, param2;`. So, Stanford's class is importing the class `acm.program` to make it simpler and faster to code. This is standard coding practice. To get the acm library available in your project take a look at this: [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)