# error: package acm.jar does not exist

Tags: java

I have this Java code:

```
import acm.program.*;
public class test extends Program 
{
    public void run () { println ("Hello World!!!");}
}
```

When I try to compile it I get this:

> izzy@izzy-VPCEB1S1E:~/Java$ javac -cp acm.jar test.java test.java:1:
>   error: package acm.jar does not exist
>
> ```
> import acm.jar.*;
> ```
>
> ^ test.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
> public class test extends Program {
>                       ^   symbol: class Program test.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
>
>
> public void run () { println ("Hello World!!!");}
>                    ^   symbol:   method println(String)   location: class test 3 errors
> ```

Comment: Is the file `acm.jar` in the current directory?

Comment: question is not clear can u please elaborate ...

Comment: If you are useing eclipse,  see this  how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: First of all, thank you guys for trying to help me

@yiding
Yes, the acm.jar is in the same directory as the source code.

Comment: NIKET BHANDARY
Could you please be more specific? What is that is not clear? This piece of code is from a tutorial from a Greek university. It told us to write this code in a text file, with the extension .java. The source file in in the same same directory as the acm.jar archive.

Comment: luoluo
Im not using eclipse. Im using Geany. The source file that i create has the extension .java. And then, i try to compile it writing in the terminal  javac -cp acm.jar test.java

Comment: The code snippet in your comment does not contain the line that `javac` is complaining about.  Please post the output of `cat test.java`.

Comment: @Matt McHenry  I'm sorry, but because I am very very beginer, how can I get the output of cat test.java? Can you tell me what exactly to type in the terminal.

Comment: @FajkorKastrioti that's exactly what you should type: `cat test.java`.  It will simply print the entire contents of the test.java file to the terminal.

Comment: @Matt McHenry I typed cat test.java in the terminal. Here's the output:
izzy@izzy-VPCEB1S1E:~/Java$ cat test.java
import acm.program.*;

public class test extends Program {
 
 public void run() { 
  println("Hello world!!!");
 }
}
izzy@izzy-VPCEB1S1E:~/Java$

Comment: @MattMcHenry By the way, this piece of code is being compiled now and running. I dont know what went wrong the first time. Anyway, thanx again for your help.