# Path for mule jars

Tags: mule

In my project I should use some external jars.

When i am adding them to build path they are not been read.

So, Could you please help me where should I place my jars so that mule can read them ?

Answer (score 3):

The recommended approach is to use a build tool such as [Maven with Mule](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Using+Maven+with+Mule). Otherwise you can also add a JAR to your project as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

you can quickly verify the .classpath file... i have also seen similar issue wherein libs added into build path were not available in the project.. In this case you can manually add the lib/jar path in .classpath file and will be able to access them

Answer (score 0):

After you add the external jars, check the order and export tab from project->properties->java Build Path -> Order and Export.

If you feel, there is a class which is present in any two or more jars, then change the order it should be read.

But if that's not the case, then try building the project from outside (using maven) and then import to eclipse using eclipse:eclipse command.

Answer (score -1):

...\AnypointStudio-3.6\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.6.0.ee_5.0.0.201501152015\mule\lib\opt

Check this path