# Importing Microba (External Package)

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I'm attempting to make use of this code so I can have an easy to add in date picker. However the only guide I can find asks me to import a jar file, which is not in the ZIP.

I assume there is another method via Build Path in Eclipse to make use of this code, but I can't read anywhere on how to successfully import it.

Link to Microba: https://github.com/tdbear/microba

Link to tutorial: http://javaandoracle.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/java-date-chooser-panel-tutorial-using.html

Any help would be much appreciated!
Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the ZIP from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/microba/files/microba/0.4.4.3/), not GitHub, that's step 1 of the tutorial. That ZIP contains the jar you're looking for. Then add it to your project in Eclipse as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse).

Comment: Ah I thought it would be out of date but the GitHub would be more reliable. Thanks Zar, I'll try now.

Comment: No problem. The zip from GitHub contains the project java files, so you wouldn't find the jar described in the tutorial there.