# Cannot resolve symbol 'DateTime'

Tags: java, datetime, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use DateTime for the first time.

I'm working with Java on IntelliJ.

I've tried writing:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
```

but I get a "Cannot resolve symbol DateTime" error.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean `DateTime` from Joda Time library? http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

Comment: Yes, that DateTime. Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 5):

You should import this class, add the following line in the beginning:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
```

Note also that JodaTime library should be somehow available to your code, either manually connected as a jar or linked through Maven or other dependency management tool.

Comment: Thank you!
would you also mind telling me how to connet the JodaTime library?

Comment: First download the archive from https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases and you'll get the joda-time-2.9.jar inside. After that, depending on your IDE, add this jar to your project. Example for Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: Note: [Joda-time's web-site](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) says: **"Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.)"** Which brings us back to the question of where is `DateTime` in `java.time`?

Comment: @IanBoyd, it's a bit more complicated than just changing the package. `java.time` does not contain `DateTime` class exactly, and the usage may (and probably will) differ. See some guide on migrating from Joda Time to Java 8's `java.time`, for example this one: https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html