# How to set jar file path to project web-inf/lib in .classpath file

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to set jar files location in build path to same project `WEB-INF/lib` folder permanently. Thanks for response in advance.

Comment: jar files usually don't have a ``WEB-INF`` folder. Are you talking abour war files?

Comment: are you looking for set jar file path into WEB-INF/lib into your .classpath file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jar in Eclipse by right-clicking on the Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the select all WEB_INF/lib jars. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse).