# Web scraping from an Iframe page

Tags: iframe, web-scraping

I'm having a lot of trouble tring to scrape some data off a page (one example is http://www.arena-offshore.com/crew-boats.html). We have permission to take the data, but they are "too busy" to give it to us in whatever form they have it in.

I have tried the Web Scraper plugin for Chrome, import.io, and started looking at more complicated programs, but they are a little beyond me. For starters, no program can seem to idenitfy the different links to each vessel, so i can;t even get to the point of scraping the individual fields. So i think if anyone knows how to grab the different links to each vessel, i can work out the rest. Anyone have any ideas? I know my skills aren't the greatest, but hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks

Alex

Comment: Do you actually know any languages or what do you plan on using to run code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Java with the HTML parser [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)? Jsoup is a great tool for parsing websites (if they don't depend on javascript) while using CSS selectors to get specific HTML elements.

---

**Java code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Scraper {

    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    static class Category {
        private int categoryNumber;
        private String title;

        public Category(int categoryNumber, String title) {
            this.categoryNumber = categoryNumber;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public int getCategoryNumber() {
            return categoryNumber;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }

    public Scraper(){
        categories.add(new Category(1, "CREW BOATS"));
        categories.add(new Category(2, "TUG BOATS"));
        categories.add(new Category(3, "AHT & AHTS"));
        categories.add(new Category(4, "SUPPLY/UTILITY VESSELS"));
        categories.add(new Category(5, "BARGES"));
        categories.add(new Category(6, "MISCELLANEOUS"));
    }

    private void scrapeCategory(Category category){

        System.out.println("\n"+category.getTitle()+"\n");
        String searchUrl = "http://www.arena-offshore.com/iframe/list/index.php?category=" + category.getCategoryNumber() + "&page=";
        int pageIndex=1;
        Document doc;

        while (true) {

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(searchUrl + pageIndex)
                        .userAgent(
                                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36")
                        .referrer("http://www.arena-offshore.com/").get();

                if (doc.select("#pu132").isEmpty()) { // no more results
                    break;
                }

                for (Element element : doc.select("#pu132")) {
                    String boat = element.select("[data-muse-uid=\"U159\"]").first().text(); //ID
                    boat += "\n\t\t" + element.select("a").first().attr("href"); //HREF
                    boat += "\n\t\t" + element.select("[data-muse-uid=\"U158\"]").get(0).text(); //TYPE
                    boat += "\n\t\t" + element.select("[data-muse-uid=\"U158\"]").get(1).text(); // LOCATION
                    boat += "\n\t\t" + element.select("[data-muse-uid=\"U153\"]").first().text(); // BRIEF DETAILS
                    System.out.println("\t"+boat);
                }

                pageIndex++;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void scrapeAllCategories(){
        for (Category category : categories) {
            scrapeCategory(category);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Scraper().scrapeAllCategories();
    }

}
```

*Note*: you need to [download the jsoup core library](https://jsoup.org/download) and [add it to your build path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280451/1661938).

---

**Output**

```
CREW BOATS

    AR-C1002
        http://www.arena-offshore.com/agent-boat-for-sale-AR-C1002.html
        AGENT BOAT
        EAST MED.
        FOR SALE 14 X 4 X 1.9 (DEPTH)M, 2007 BUILT 630 BHP, 12 PERSONEL, IN EAST MED.

    ...

    AR-C1000
        http://www.arena-offshore.com/AR-KED.html?page=13
        CREW BOAT
        SOUTH AMERICA
        FOR SALE 17 X 5 X 2.18M, 2009 BUILT 1200 BHP, IN SOUTH AMERICA

TUG BOATS

    AR-KTK
        http://www.arena-offshore.com/single-screw-tug-boat-AR-KTK.html
        SINGLE SCREW
        TURKEY
        FOR SALE 1998 BUILT/ 2008 REBUILT 1000 HP / 16 TBP

    ...

AHT & AHTS

    AR-RZA
        http://www.arena-offshore.com/AR-RZA.html
        ANCHOR HANDLING TUG / TOWING
        AFRICA
        FOR SALE 36 X 10 X 4 M (MAX DRAFT) 4400 BHP / 58 TBP

    ...

SUPPLY/UTILITY VESSELS

    AR-U5001
        http://www.arena-offshore.com/survey-vessel-in-south-east-asia-AR-U5001.html
        SURVEY SUPPOT VESSEL
        SOUTH EAST ASIA
        FOR SALE 20 X 6 X 1.5 (DRAFT)M, 2012 BUILT, IRS CLASS 650 BHP, 50 M2 DECK SPACE

    ...

BARGES

    AR-KLM
        http://www.arena-offshore.com/AR-KLM.html
        ACCOMMODATION
        SHETLANDS
        FOR CHARTER 1993 BUILT MAJOR CONVERSION 2004 AND 2013

    ...

MISCELLANEOUS

    AR-SAA
        http://www.arena-offshore.com/AR-SAA.html
        SHALLOW DRAFT MPP / WORKBOAT
        -
        FOR CHARTER 2800 HP / 37.3 TBP CERTIFIED

    ...
```

*Note:* shortened output, instead of `...` there are a lot more results printed.

Comment: Thanks so much, ill try that when i get home tonight

Comment: @AlexBaird Is this resolved? If so, please consider accepting it as an answer or post a follow up question here.

Comment: Thanks F.Klein. Because i'm new to this it's taking me a little longer than i thought but it's in process!

Comment: Please delete if not appropriate. Can i contact you directly F.Klein? Would you be interested in paid work for the few occasions where the simple methods of scraping do not work?

Comment: When you go to my profile page there is on the right side under my location information a link to my github profile, which displays my email address.

Comment: emailed through to you