# Maven: Fails to detect package in dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a simple test maven project (on Eclipse Neon) in which I try to link to a class on another jar of mine.

The project structure is displayed on the following image:

[image]

Log4jManager is the project of the "3rd party" jar.
Log4jEx is the client which tries to use it.

You may see in aaaa.java that the imports point to the correct path of packages in Log4jManager. And yet, they fail to compile.

This is the pom file:

[image]

Can you assist please?

Thank you, Tal

---

UPDATE:

Following a friend suggestion, I installed InteliJ and created the same project. there were no problems here:

[image]

So it appears to be an Eclipse issue... :(

Comment: Try to add the your Log4j to the classpath. You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Just "clean project" (project menu -> clean) and everything will be fine. Eclipse restart can be helpfull as well. This is typical Eclipse issue that happens to me from time to time.

In general:
If your project compiles fine from the console (`mvn clean compile`) then you can ignore such Eclipse artefacts as they will most likely disapear.

Comment: Thanks. What I did eventually was to delete the project and recreate it. This time - there wereno problems... :) Awkward, but this is what we've got... :(

Comment: @dushkin this haapens from time to time to Eclipse.