# ClassNotFoundException HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, classnotfoundexception, apache-spark-standalone

I am trying to run a Spark sample in local mode, but am getting the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/io/HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.<init>(SQLConf.scala:383)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.<clinit>(SQLConf.scala)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$$anonfun$buildConf$1.apply(SQLConf.scala:930)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$$anonfun$buildConf$1.apply(SQLConf.scala:928)
at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder$$anonfun$createWithDefault$1.apply(ConfigBuilder.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder$$anonfun$createWithDefault$1.apply(ConfigBuilder.scala:122)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.createWithDefault(ConfigBuilder.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.<init>(SQLConf.scala:937)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.<clinit>(SQLConf.scala)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$sessionStateClassName(SparkSession.scala:962)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
at com.megaport.PipelineExample$.main(PipelineExample.scala:37)
at com.megaport.PipelineExample.main(PipelineExample.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I can see the class in the GitHub repo, but it is not in the Maven lib, or in the distro(I have the distro bundled with Hadoop) spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.jar.

The code I am trying to run is taken from the examples in the Spark distro, and it fails at the getOrCreate stage...

```
// scalastyle:off println
package com.megaport

// $example on$
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, Tokenizer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
// $example off$
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object PipelineExample {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .appName("My Spark Application")  // optional and will be autogenerated if not specified
  .master("local[*]")               // avoid hardcoding the deployment environment
//      .enableHiveSupport()              // self-explanatory, isn't it?
  .getOrCreate

// $example on$
// Prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
val training = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0L, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
  (1L, "b d", 0.0),
  (2L, "spark f g h", 1.0),
  (3L, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0)
)).toDF("id", "text", "label")

// Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of three stages: tokenizer, hashingTF, and lr.
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("words")
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setNumFeatures(1000)
  .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
  .setOutputCol("features")
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.01)
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, lr))

// Fit the pipeline to training documents.
val model = pipeline.fit(training)

// Now we can optionally save the fitted pipeline to disk
model.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")

// We can also save this unfit pipeline to disk
pipeline.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/unfit-lr-model")

// And load it back in during production
val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")

// Prepare test documents, which are unlabeled (id, text) tuples.
val test = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (4L, "spark i j k"),
  (5L, "l m n"),
  (6L, "mapreduce spark"),
  (7L, "apache hadoop")
)).toDF("id", "text")

// Make predictions on test documents.
model.transform(test)
  .select("id", "text", "probability", "prediction")
  .collect()
  .foreach { case Row(id: Long, text: String, prob: Vector, prediction: Double) =>
    println(s"($id, $text) --> prob=$prob, prediction=$prediction")
  }
// $example off$

spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the dependencies in your POM file.  If the dependencies are correct, and the class is in the JAR in the Maven Central repo, then Maven should download the JAR an put it into your local repo.

Comment: The trouble is that the class is not in the jar file obtained by Maven, and it is not in the jar file that comes with the Spark distro.  I've used jarfind.com to try and find out where to get it but there are no results...  I can see the source file in the GitHub repository, but I don't know what Jar file it gets put into...

Comment: I suspect that you are (in effect) using a version of Spark that is ahead of the latest version published to Maven Central.  You will either need to fetch the source and do a local build, then put the artifacts into your local repo ... or get rid of whatever it it that is dependent on the pre-release version in GitHub.

Comment: I will try that, Stephen C

Comment: Stephen C - you are correct - could you please 'answer' the question, and I will mark it as correct.  It looks like the doco was just cutting over from the 2.1.0 release...

Comment: Hi @user1817243, could you please explain how did you fix this issue?

Comment: <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: Hi Fattah Safa, if you use the mvn dependencies above you will be fine - I was using an older version of MLLib

Answer (score 0):

Well if its not in your java library, then you should download the dependent jar and add it.
Check this SO for more details

[How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)