# JAX Rest Service is returning internal server error in my friends system ,but the same application is running well in my system

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, tomcat8, jquery-ajaxq

In my system,the application is running smooth, I have zipped the whole application including jars and my friend has imported that code and while running the application,it is returning the error as :

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
    MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class org.json.simple.JSONObject, genericType=class org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

we are unable to add new method even,new path is not getting mapped to the service.we are using tomcat8.0 as server.
Everything is same including the jars ,I have sent the whole application to her in zip format ,I don't know why we are getting this exception from the service.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did she add the jars to the properties section of her application / project?
Something like this (depending on IDE): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: I have already kept all the jars in the web-inf folder. I have given the complete application including the jars.We are using eclipse neon edition

Comment: Did you zip it from within Eclipse's archiving function or did you zip it from Windows?  If it was from Windows, it may not have retained all of your Eclipse properties for the project.

Comment: Yes I zipped it from windows .yes it  was the problem ..Thank you so much.rectified that