# How do I use last.fm api in java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, last.fm

I'm trying to use the last.fm api in eclipse for a school project, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that. I'm using java to write my code and javafx to create my project. Any information help.

Comment: Ask a concrete question.

Answer (score -1):

You should download its api from [this site](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Clastfm-java). Under download colum, there is a jar, click on it. The Jar will be downloaded to your local computer.

and then, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse) to import your jar file to your project.

Comment: Yes. Do you mind me asking how I can implement that api into a search engine in my java eclipse?

Comment: @snapkin If this answer solved your problem, please kindly accept upvote it and accept it. It helps also future users, who have similar problems.

Comment: You can ask your new question with a new post and give me please URL here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943143/how-do-i-implement-last-fm-api-as-a-search-engine-in-java-eclipse Thanks! @AdInfinitum