# No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2: in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a remote database using the following java code, but I get an error saying no suitable driver found

I have included the required db2 libraries in my project:

[image]

I have declared the jdbc settings in the main class

```
Settings.loadSettings();

Class.forName("Settings.DB2_JDBC_DRIVER");

Controller con = new Controller();
con.business_logic();
}
```

Then trying to connect the database in another class

```
public Connection getDBConnection()
{
Connection DBConnection = null;
try {
  System.out.println("Connecting to  database " + Settings.DBName + ".");
  String DBURL = "jdbc:db2://" + Settings.DBServer + ":" + Settings.DBPort + 
 "/" + Settings.DBName + ";";
  String decryptedPass = decryptPassString(Settings.DBPass);
  DBConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, Settings.DBUser, 
  decryptedPass);
  System.out.println("Database connection successfully established to  
  database " + Settings.DBName + " using user " + Settings.DBUser + ".");
  return DBConnection;
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("An unexpected error occurred when attempting to 
 establish connection to  database " + Settings.DBName + ". The error was: " 
 + e.getMessage() + "\r\n" + e.getMessage()); }
return DBConnection;
}
```

can anyone please explain what i am missing here ?

The error message i am receiving is

An unexpected error occurred when attempting to establish connection to database DWHER00. The error was: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2:/

Comment: are you sure that `Class.forName` is not throwing an Exception? Is the Exception being ignored?

Answer (score 7):

The line:

```
Class.forName("Settings.DB2_JDBC_DRIVER");
```

should ideally be something like this:

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
```

unless you are creating your own driver for DB2.

You will need the JAR files for the DB2 installation that you are using.

Put them in the class path and make the above code change. And it should work.

---

**IBM DB2 Universal Driver Type 4**

Driver Class Name:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Driver Jar Files: `db2jcc.jar` and `db2jcc_license_cu.jar`
(Both of these jars must be included)

JDBC URL Format:

```
jdbc:db2://<host>[:<port>]/<database_name>
```

JDBC URL Examples:

```
jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/SAMPLE
```

---

**IBM DB2 Universal Driver Type 2**

Driver Class Name:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Driver Jar Files: `db2jcc.jar` and `db2jcc_license_cu.jar`
(Both of these jars must be included)

JDBC URL Format:

```
jdbc:db2:<database_name>
```

JDBC URL Examples:

```
jdbc:db2:sample
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help , Found the problem and fixed it . its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the /lib folder is added to the build path of your project as well. See here [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)