# Box2D BodyEditorLoader cannot be accessed?

Tags: box2d

I am trying to create some accurate hitboxes for my game and I have recently found out about this physics body editor that allows me to do just that: http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/.

My problem is that when I try to set up the BodyEditorLoader, Java simply acts as if it did not exist. Do I have to install something external in order to set up this body loader? I am 100% sure that I have the latest Box2D version.

Comment: Are you using LibGDX? as I don't see it tagged here and this is what's written on the site "Loader provided for LibGDX game framework"

Comment: @dfour Yes, I am

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated your using LibGDX then you should be able to download the Body Editor with the loaders from  [Physics Body Editor v2.9.2 (with loaders)](https://code.google.com/archive/p/box2d-editor/downloads) .

In the zip you will find 2 .jar files which you need to add to your project.

```
bodyeditor-loader.jar
bodyeditor-loader-sources.jar
```

Comment: Thank you, but excuse my beginner question: how do I add the loaders to my project?

Comment: This stack overflow question explains it well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse