# How can I use this javafx library?

Tags: eclipse, javafx

[image]

I am trying to design gui on java.

I will use this javafx library https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa

I downloaded this lib but how can I used it?

I added external jar on my javafx project but I can not make any sample code work.

I'm working with eclipse neon and java 8. By the way I set up javafx. It is okay.

Do I need anything else for using this library?

I have gradle and maven plug-in my eclipse IDE.

Comment: Try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse) SO article. Update your question with everything you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Don't directly download this file, use something like maven or gradle for this:

If you scroll down on this page: https://bintray.com/hansolo/Medusa/Medusa you will find the copy-paste parts.

There even is an example-project using that lib: https://github.com/HanSolo/medusademo

Comment: ı set up maven and gradle plug-in eclipses ,but ı do not understand how ı used these copy-parts

Comment: Just checkout the demo-project, everything is already setup for you. You might want to learn maven/gradle basics first, without the IDE (as these build-tools are IDE-agnostic)