# How to install OAuth (e.g. apache oltu) in order to use an API with Eclipse for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, oauth, oltu

I want to use oauth to be able to use a certain API from a website. But due to my limited programming experience, I seem to be unable to install apache oltu correctly.

After two hours of searching I am now posting the question original question which brought me to apache maven and apache oltu:
**What do I need to do to make the 'import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;' command in eclipse for java work?**

Right now it is giving me the 'The import oauth cannot be resolved.' error. I tried downloading the apache oltu package, unzipped it and put it in the java folder but that does not seem to tell eclipse, that it is there.

I feel like I am not very specific right now, but on the other hand it seems like a very basic question. I will surely try to respond as good as I can, if there is any information missing.

Thanks in advance for any helpful answer!
Peter :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this jar in your PATH.  Refer this [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

It looks like your eclipse cannot find the oauth package in its PATH so it is unable to import the package