# Eclipse java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying out the stopwatch class in http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/Stopwatch.java.html . I'm using Eclipse, and here are the things I've done-

Here's the code -

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // sum of square roots of integers from 1 to n using Math.sqrt(x).
        Stopwatch timer1 = new Stopwatch();
        double sum1 = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum1 += Math.sqrt(i);
        }
        double time1 = timer1.elapsedTime();
        StdOut.printf("%e (%.2f seconds)\n", sum1, time1);

        // sum of square roots of integers from 1 to n using Math.pow(x, 0.5).
        Stopwatch timer2 = new Stopwatch();
        double sum2 = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum2 += Math.pow(i, 0.5);
        }
        double time2 = timer2.elapsedTime();
        StdOut.printf("%e (%.2f seconds)\n", sum2, time2);
    }

}
```

I've added external JAR stdlib to the Java buildpath

However, when I run it, I still get the error-

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSEAM.png)

Could someone please help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I followed the steps outlined here- [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Thank you everyone for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `StdOut` lines. That class does not exist in the JDK. Generally it is used for teaching purposes, as [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdOut.java.html).

So, to solve your class not found exception replace them like here:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // sum of square roots of integers from 1 to n using Math.sqrt(x).
        Stopwatch timer1 = new Stopwatch();
        double sum1 = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum1 += Math.sqrt(i);
        }
        double time1 = timer1.elapsedTime();
        System.out.println(String.format("%e (%.2f seconds)\n", sum1, time1));

        // sum of square roots of integers from 1 to n using Math.pow(x, 0.5).
        Stopwatch timer2 = new Stopwatch();
        double sum2 = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum2 += Math.pow(i, 0.5);
        }
        double time2 = timer2.elapsedTime();
        System.out.println(String.format("%e (%.2f seconds)\n", sum2, time2));
    }
}
```

As you may notice, now there are two `System.out.println`.

Comment: I understand, but the issue I'm facing is, despite adding the stlib.jar (which is where StdOut is defined) to the build path why am I getting a NoClassDefFound error?

Comment: did you make a Clean/Build of your source code, then?

Comment: Hey, that also solves the problem!

Comment: glad it helped.