# I am having trouble understanding how to set up Jexel in Eclipse

Tags: java, excel, eclipse

I was told JExel was a good way to work with excel files in java, but I'm having trouble understanding how to set it up.  I'm playing around in java with different things to expand my knowledge. I thought libraries and such were a good way to start.

I added my jars - but when I put import jxl.Cell; at the top of my class, it tells me that isn't anything.

I'm trying to ask the users for an excel sheet, but if I'm not using the library correctly, I'm stuck point blank.

I was wondering if someone knew how to give a beginner step by step advice on setting it up in eclipse. I have no where else to turn and am evidently not understanding the steps given.

Comment: Post the code you've tried please.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful: [Importing Jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Once this is done, all you need to do is import it in your java classes. I have never used jexcel so i can't comment on specifics, perhaps `import jxl.Cell` is not valid? Try simply doing `import jxl.*` , that will import all of the classes in the `jxl` library.

As a side note, this way of managing libraries with external JARs is fine for small projects while you are just learning, however once you get more advanced I would consider learning how to use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), it will make life easier.