# Error list of services Apache-axis

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm trying to mount a SOAP server and I'm getting the following error when I click to the service options of the Axis apache. I'm using apache-tomcat-8, axis2-1.7.6 and java 9.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. I'm new in java and sorry if the informatión is not enough.

[image]

```
[WARN] Web application uses org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet; please update web.xml to use org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet instead
[WARN] Unable to load manifest for StAX implementation at jrt:/java.xml/
[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer; see debug logs for more details
nov. 13, 2017 8:59:03 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 24 more

nov. 13, 2017 8:59:03 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [AxisAdminServlet] in web application [/test_server] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

nov. 13, 2017 8:59:04 P. M. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
nov. 13, 2017 8:59:04 P. M. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
nov. 13, 2017 8:59:04 P. M. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 10198 ms
[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer; see debug logs for more details
nov. 13, 2017 8:59:48 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 31 more

nov. 13, 2017 8:59:48 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Excepción de reserva de espacio para servlet [AxisServlet]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

[WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer; see debug logs for more details
nov. 13, 2017 9:08:15 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [jsp] en el contexto con ruta [/test_server] lanzó la excepción [Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP [/axis2-web/HappyAxis.jsp] en línea [340]

337:             OMElement payload = createEnvelope();
338:             ConfigurationContext configctx =
339:                     ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);
340:             ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(configctx, null);
341:             EndpointReference targetEPR = new EndpointReference(IP + configctx.getServicePath() + "/Version");
342:             Options options = new Options();
343:             client.setOptions(options);


Stacktrace:] con causa raíz
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.utils.NamespacePrefixList
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.createAnonymousService(ServiceClient.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:143)
    at org.apache.jsp.axis2_002dweb.HappyAxis_jsp.invokeTheService(HappyAxis_jsp.java:327)
    at org.apache.jsp.axis2_002dweb.HappyAxis_jsp._jspService(HappyAxis_jsp.java:556)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer; see debug logs for more details
nov. 13, 2017 9:11:04 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 31 more

nov. 13, 2017 9:11:04 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Excepción de reserva de espacio para servlet [AxisServlet]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>test_server</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>/axis2-web/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using (Intellij, eclipse,...)? Which build tool are using (Maven, Gradle,...)?

Comment: I'm using eclipse. More or less I'm following this tutorial http://www.javahelps.com/2016/04/apache-axis2-hello-world-using-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
```

According to error above, you should do one of the following:

- Import the jar of the class `URIResolver` to your project (For example, if you use Maven, then add it as dependency to `pom.xml`)
- Add the jar of the class `URIResolver` to your [classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse).

And align `web.xml`. It is not valid xml. The last part is commented.

Comment: Ok, I've changed it. Now I'm getting a error message that says that the prefix wsdl for element is not bound Axis `ERROR:  'El prefijo "wsdl" para el elemento "wsdl:definitions" no está enlazado.'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: El prefijo "wsdl" para el elemento "wsdl:definitions" no está enlazado.'
nov. 13, 2017 9:56:14 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet [AxisServlet] lanzó excepción`

Comment: It means the xml content does not match the schema. I see that part of the xml is commented, is it in purpose? I mean it doesn't seem like a valid xml.

Comment: Sorry, it's a stackoverflow 'bug'. The code in my program is not commented