# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while trying to send emails via SMTP (Java)

Tags: java, smtp

Trying to make my program send emails to myself, using java, and I am being very unsuccessful. I keep getting an error related to the class

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
    at Running.main(Running.java:22)`.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataHandler`

The error I am getting is on this line of code:

`Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);`

Comment: Have you set classpath properly for mail.jar, activation.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this line: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataHandler`. It means that the `DataHandler` class could not be found anywhere and hence exception was raised. Upon a quick search, I found that the missing class belongs to [JAF (activation.jar)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html#DataHandler(javax.activation.DataSource)).

Basics: Where are files searched during compilation?

1. Source directories specified by you during java compilation. Usually this is done through any build configuration file like `pom.xml` for Maven or `build.gradle` for Gradle.
2. Dependencies are usually defined and stored in classpath. The class path is a sequence of directories (or zip files) where `javac` compiler searches for classes not defined in any of the source files.

Unblock by add missing jars to classpath, [follow this for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280384/3991696):

1. Add [javax.activation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/package-summary.html) jar to your classpath and check whether this resolves your issue.
2. Since you are trying to send emails via SMTP, you may want to add [JavaMail (mail.jar)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) to your classpath instead and the other `activation.jar` would be added automatically because of transitive dependency.

Comment: What do you mean by add `javax.activation`? How do I add it? Sorry.. I'm new to this stuff, and very confused.

Comment: Same error getting in Ant project, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
IDE: Netbeans