# Incorrect data getting fetched from select query

Tags: java, sql

Can someone review my code

This query is fetching two values `address_id` and `postcode` from `table1`. Here 
`AddressID` class has two variable `postcode`(string) and `address_id`(integer) :

```
@Select("SELECT address_id,postcode FROM table1 WHERE custom_field_1 = #{caseid}")
public List<AddressID> getAddressIdPostCodeList(String caseid);
```

Here is how AddressID looks **AddressID.java**

```
  private int addressId;

  private String postcode;

    //getters and setters of Pstcode and addressId

    @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "PostCode : " + this.postcode;

        }
```

while executing this query I get value of `address_id` as 0 and required `postcode`. Although DB has values of `address_id` which is not zero. Where my code is failing?

This is where in my main method I am calling

```
 List<AddressID> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
 addresses = mainClassObject.getAddressIdPostCodeList(address.getcaseId());
```

Ideally addresses  object should have both `address_id` and `postcode`. I am getting both values but `address_id` I am getting 0 and correct values for `postcode`.

Comment: So where is the code that actually runs that query and populates your Java instances?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I am calling that method in my implementation class like this   List<AddressID> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
 addresses = mainClassObject.getAddressIdPostCodeList(address.getcaseId());  and as you can see in my above piece of code posted in my question that this method returns me result from query getAddressIdPostCodeList()

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant comment because I dont have 50 reputation, I had to write it here, its hard to tell from the code you posted, to give you an answer I need more detail on what `getAddressIdPostCodeList()` does, since you said the data in the DB has no ceros the error must be in the method `getAddressIdPostCodeList()` and/or in how you are handling the `resultset` of the Query

**EDIT: Solution using Oracle JDBC Driver**

Since I dont know how to use `Mybatis`, heres a solution using `JDBC`.

to connect using JDBC to your `Oracle` DB here's a simple tutorial:

**1.** First you need to download de `JDBC` driver from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) depending your DB version (11g,12c,10g), the driver Its called `ojdbcX.jar` where X is a number of the version of the driver

**2.** After you have downloaded the driver you need to add the `.jar` to your project, if you are using **Netbeans IDE** you can add it like this:

[image: Adding JAR to NetBeans project]

if you are using Eclipse you can use the following Link to see how to add the `.JAR` file: [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

**3.** After adding the `.JAR` its pretty simple, you just need to connect to the DB using your credentials, here is an example on how to do it:

```
Connection connection = null;
            try {
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "password");                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

for more deatiled information on how to connect, you can check the [oracle.jdbc
Class OracleDriver](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) Documentation

**4.** After the connection has been made its pretty simple, Heres a short code example to get the result you want, you need to modify it with your connection details and as you see fit because im making a couple of assumptions, this code is just an example:

**Main.Java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

           List<AddressID> addresses;
           SQLConnect conex= new SQLConnect();
           String caseid="the id you want";
           addresses=conex.getAddressIdPostCodeList(caseid);
}
```

**AddressID.java**

```
public class AddressID {

private String addressId;
private String postcode;     
}
```

**SQLConnect.Java**

```
public class SQLConnect {


   public static Connection connection;

            public SQLConnect (){
                createConnection();    
              }


            public void CreateConnection(){
             try {
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "password")
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }


            public void closeConnection(){
                if(connection!=null){
                    try {
                        connection.close();   
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                         ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            public ResultSet ExecuteQuery(String queryTXT) throws SQLException{

             Statement query = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet table=query.executeQuery(queryTXT);
             return table;                   
            }


            public List<AddressID> getAddressIdPostCodeList(String caseid) throws SQLException{
             List<AddressID> addresses = new ArrayList <> ();
             ResultSet table=ExecuteQuery("SELECT address_id,postcode FROM table1 WHERE custom_field_1 ='"+caseid+"';");
              while (table.next()) {
                 AddressID aux;
                 aux.addressId=table.getString(1); 
                 aux.postcode=table.getString(2);                           
                 addresses.add(aux); 
              }       
             return addresses;                 
            }
 }
```

Comment: This is my repository class.I guess thats how we use for writing queries.This method is only executing select query...        @Select("SELECT address_id,postcode FROM table name WHERE custom_field_1  = #{caseId}")
 public List<AddressID> getAddressIdPostCodeList(String caseId);

Comment: What database are you using ? (Oracle,SQL-Server,etc...) and
What are you using to connect to the database ? jdbc ?

Comment: I am using Oracle and mybatis

Comment: I've never used mybatis, If you want i can give you a solution using `JDBC` for your problem, but if you need to use necessarily mybatis I can't help you, sorry

Comment: My application use mybatis.still I want to know what is the solution using jdbc...I think the issue in my code could be AddressID,java class.Can you check if I am missing anything there.I converted toString the Postcode as it is string.As address id is integer.Unable to understand it what is wrong with code

Comment: Im gonna write you a solution using `JDBC`, regarding your `AdressID` class, have you tried changing `private int addressId;` to `private String addressId;` and handling it just like you handle `postcode` ?

Comment: Kewl Yes I did.I was getting null instead of 0..:(..But checked in DB.It has got values..It has values of datatype Number

Comment: I have provided a solution using `JDBC` editing the same answer above, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
I did forgot to wtite my result query which is actually binding data fetched 
from select query to the AddressId class..

@Results(id = "result", 
value = {
    @Result(property = "addressId", column = "address_id"),
    @Result(property = "postcode", column = "postcode")
        }
        )
```