# Unable to connect to Google Cloud through Eclipse, and newInstance function getting crossed out

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-platform

Hello I have this simple java code running in Eclipse in mac, just trying to connect to my google cloud database.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdb:mysql://XX.XXX.X.XXX/test","root","1234");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from cars");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)); 
    }
    connection.close();
  }

}
```

The problem I have is that when I use the newInstance function, Eclipse crosses it out, and when I run my program I get the Error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdb:mysql://XX.XXX.X.XXX/test`

Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The "crossed out" means that the method is deprecated and shouldn't be used any more. I'm not sure about the error. (`Class.newInstance` is deprecated in Java 9 and above, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) for more info)

Comment: @apemanzilla  Could you post this as an answer, please? I would probably include the description below "Deprecated" in the link you posted.

Comment: @RubénC. I didn't post it as an answer because it doesn't answer the main question about the exception, it just explains what the "crossed out" means.

Comment: @apemanzilla I thought your suggestion could solve the issue but as a matter of fact Class.forName(...).newInstance() didn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem in your code is that you lack a “c” in “jdb”. Replace:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdb:mysql://XX.XXX.X.XXX/test","root","1234");
```

with:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XX.XXX.X.XXX/test","root","1234");
```

Verify that you have also imported the JAR files into Eclipse as described in  [this related old SO case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse).

As @apemanzilla said in his comment, the cross out means that the method [is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()).  The following lines explain how to update it:

> The call  `class.newInstance()` can be replaced by `class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`