# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/jsonwebtoken/SignatureAlgorithm wildfly

Tags: java, jwt, wildfly

I'm trying to use wildfly 12 with jersey and jwt

I have my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I put my .war in deployments directory that works; but it doesn't work on my eclipse server.

Comment: [how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Comment: I'm using maven

Comment: Can you please explain better. If I understood well if you deploy manually on a wildfly instance it works, but when you start the app within the server defined in Eclipse it is failing. Is that correct?

Comment: that's right cisk

Comment: @FelipeFlores Try double click on server definition in eclipse and in the server configuration window there should be a section called "server location", select the 2nd option (the one saying "Use server installation - takes control of server installation" or something similar). In this way you will deploy your app physically to the server deployment directory, because by default eclipse creates a copy of the server inside your workspace/.metadata/etc.... and it will use that. Hope this helps.

Comment: @cisk I'm not finding these options

Comment: @FelipeFlores http://oi64.tinypic.com/35jkn53.jpg

Answer (score 0):

add the dependency as it states:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```