# Adding prime faces to Eclipse project build path doesn't render elements

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am trying to add prime faces to a new dynamic web project on eclipse so as instructed in [the official website](https://www.primefaces.org/gettingstarted/)

> You just need to download PrimeFaces, add the primefaces-{version}.jar
>   to your classpath and import the namespace to get started.

To do this

1. I created new dynamic web project in eclipse
2. Right click on the project in project explorer -> Build path -> configure build path -> Libraries ->Add external jar

however  using the template xhtml file provided didn't render primefaces tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that

1. the jar itself must be placed in WebContent\WEB-INF\lib
2. then right click on that jar -> add to build path

note that using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420543/3061221) solution doesn't work (creating lib folder under java resourses(