# How to add dependency in maven so Eclipse can use it on the buildpath

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

Very often I get this error in Eclipse, saying that some classes are not present on the build path.

For eg, now it can not find the class "cucumber.api.java.After". This class  do exist in the jar "cucumber-java-1.2.5.jar"
And if you take a look at the pom.xml in the image below you see that that dependency is included in the project.

But why does not my beloved Eclipse find it? 
Best regards
Fredrik

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

I feel a bit silly now. But a Refresh of all projects and a Maven > Update Project with "Force update ..." actually solved the problem.
Must try to remember that.

Comment: Strange that Eclipse did not suggest that solution though,